# struct erreur while assigning a char

Tags: c

I have this error :

> warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast `[-Wint-conversion]`
>   `TabPart[0].nom[20]="alami";`

while compiling this code :

```
typedef struct
{
  char nom[20];
  char prenom[30];
  int dej;
  int din;
  int hot;
  int num;
}Participant;

Participant TabPart[10];
TabPart[0].nom[20]="alami";
TabPart[0].prenom[30]="iliass";
TabPart[0].dej=0;
TabPart[0].din=1;
TabPart[0].hot=2;
TabPart[0].num=1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to assign a `char *` to an element of a char array, which is not what you want to do.  You could use strcpy to copy it into the array, or you can instead initialize the character array with a string literal.

```
typedef struct
{
  char nom[20];
  char prenom[30];
  int dej;
  int din;
  int hot;
  int num;
}Participant;

Participant TabPart[10] = {{"alami", "iliass", 0, 1, 2, 1}};
```

Alternatively, you can use a designated initializer to be more explicit about what each field is:

```
Participant TabPart[10] = {{ .nom = "alami", .prenom = "iliass", .dej = 0,
        .din = 1, .hot = 2, .num = 1}};
```

Answer (score 2):

```
TabPart[0].nom[20]="alami";
```

You should replace this by

```
strcpy(TabPart[0].nom, "alami");
```

TabPart.nom[0] is a `char`, while "alami" is a `char*` (i.e. a `pointer to a char`).

You cannot assign to a `char` a `pointer to a char`, as they are not compatible.

Comment: Note also that TabPart.nom[20] is out of bounds, and even assigning a char to it will cause an error.

Answer (score 1):

You cant just assign a char in a struct with an = sign. You need to use a function like strcpy to copy it into the char array.